# Importing only one user data from a Dump file

Tags: oracle-11g, impdp, expdp

I am using oracle 11gr1 SingleByte Database,

I am trying to import a Dump file. but strangely the dump file contains multiple user objects(i.e, Import(IMPDP) is not done properly).

```
example:
. . "TEST"."AUDVALUES"                     174.5 MB 2136286 rijen geëxporteerd
. . "TRAIN"."AUDVALUES"                    105.5 MB 1311686 rijen geëxporteerd
```

Note: There are SYSMAN objects also imported into DUMP file, I should exclude them as well

I want to import only TEST objects not TRAIN objects to target DB? Is it possible to achieve?

Please get back to me if question is not understandable?

Answer (score 1):

the impdp utility has the SCHEMAS option to select only the schema you need:

```
impdp SCHEMAS=TEST
```

You can also remap the schema: importing TEST schema into TEST2 using the remap_schema option